# Google Maps Api V3 - Assigning Multiple Listeners to Same Marker Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently working on a project to upgrade our Goole Maps API from v2 to v3 and ran into an issue and need confirmation on whether it's possible to register multiple listeners to the same marker. Can anyone confirm whether Goole Maps API v3 supports multiple listeners on the same marker like API v2 can?

Sample Code:

```
var mapObject = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var points = new Array();
var markers = new Array();

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.260081, -117.279369),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,                  
    panControl: true,                    
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
}

map = new google.maps.Map(mapObject, mapOptions);

points.push(lat:'33.260081', lng:'-117.279369');
points.push(lat:'33.260079', lng:'-117.279371');
points.push(lat:'33.260083', lng:'-117.279373');

for (var i in points) {

    var point = points[i];

    var marker = initMarker(point);

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        alert('mouseover');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        alert('click');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        alert('mouseout');
    });

    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng));
}
```

When I hover over the marker, it alerts with 'mouseout', then 'mouseover' twice. I would expect it to just alert with 'mouseover' once.

When I click a marker it alerts with 'click', then 'mouseout', then 'click', then 'mouseover'. I would expect it to just alert 'click'.

When I disable 'mouseover' and 'mouseout', 'click' works as expected. And when I disable 'click' and 'mouseout', 'mouseover' works as expected.

Is there any reason why these events seem to chain to each other? In API v2 we were able to support this functionality no problem.

Thanks in advance.

-- Edit --

This only appears to be happening in Firefox and IE, Chrome handles the events as expected.

-- Edit --

I have gone ahead and setup 2 map demos so a side-by-side comparison 
can be done.

Version 2 Url: http://map.ownij.com/index2.php

Version 3 Url: http://map.ownij.com/

**Version 2** even listener behavior in **Firefox, IE, Chrome**:

- mouseover: mouseover
- click: click
- mouseout: mouseout

**Version 3** event listener behavior in **Firefox, IE**:

- mouseover: mouseout, mouseover, mouseover
- click: click, mouseout, click
- mouseout: mouseout, mouseout

**Version 3** even listener behavior in **Chrome**:

- mouseover: mouseover
- click: click
- mouseout: mouseout

As you can see, v3 event behavior works as expected in chrome, but in 
FF and IE, each event triggers multiple listeners which results in 
unusual behavior.

We built our maps to allow a map bubble to appear 
when a user hovers over a marker, so when the mouseover fires the 
mouseout event, the bubble re-renders indefinitely until the user 
moves the mouse off the marker.

We cannot release our v3 upgrade until this has been resolved, 
otherwise we rob our clients of current functionality.

-- Edit --

Updated code, by changing alerts to console.log() calls, the events fire as expected. It appears there is some unusual event handling with respect to non-infowindow calls (alerts, ebubble, etc.).

Comment: The event model is slightly different between the browsers.  Off-hand I don't recall how to fix this, but remember once reading that perhaps how the events bubble up can be changed...

Comment: @YzmirRamirez: Unfortunately this has nothing to do with the events bubble, just the event handling of the browsers, that's why I opted to just do alerts to take away any extraneous distractors.

Comment: Avoid using "alert". The popup can cause additional events such as mouseover, mouseout etc. - use `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just doing away with the hover listener and going with click listener. Would eventually like to add the hover functionality back, but don't have the time to track it down now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably these additional events are caused by `alert`. Try logging the events in a way that does not interact with the mouse, for example using `console.log` (not sure if that by now is available in internet exploder though).

Simply speaking, my guess is that the popup causes your mouse to "mouseout" (and "mouseover" the popup). etc. the additional events then are probably caused when the popup disappears again.

Comment: You are correct, I changed alerts to console.log() and the events fire as expected. It appears that when a non-infowindow is used, it fires the extra events. I am trying to get it to work with a customized version of the ebubble plugin.

Comment: Anything in HTML is actually supposed to cause events such as mouseover and mouseout, so you won't be able to really work around these, but you must treat them with their intended meaning: the mouse is now on the infowindow, not the marker. A workaround that may be possible for you is however to put the popup layer *below* the map target layer. Then the events should work as expected, however interaction with the popup may be broken...

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, what I am getting hung up on is the event listeners in v2 worked as expected, even with focus being set to a custom info window.